# Web Based File explorer in .net

Tags: .net, file, user-interface, listbox, explorer

I want to develop a web based file explorer in .net which will get the file details from a remote server.

I just want to see the file lists and size.

here is the link for screenshot https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B-apk90xOQikZjQ3MDE5YzMtYWJjNS00OTc4LWI0MDQtODRiYzg5YTIxZGE2

Its smthing similat to globus online file transfer UI.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use classes from System.IO namespace. Use `File/FileInfo`, `Directory/DirectoryInfo` and `Path` classes ([Tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8881/Web-File-Manager)).

Comment: Actually I am working on a web project in C#. I need to connect to the remote server over FTP and get the listing. I could do it using listbox. but It does not look good.